# Assign another tester in a Test Run in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, testing, integration-testing, microsoft-test-manager

I'm testing a Test Case with a few steps in Microsft Test Manager.
When I run this Test Case, I want to execute only a few steps and then assign another tester to this Test Run.

E.g.
I have three steps. The first two steps are for me to test.
After those two steps, I want to stop testing and assign another tester so that he can test the third step.

[image: three steps in test case]

But I can't find a way to stop testing, and assign a new user to this Test Case.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **definitely** cannot be done. When you run a `Test Case` a new `Test Run` is created and stored in the tfs database. The steps executed for this run and their result, comments, attachments e.t.c. are saved and cannot be edited.

From a test point of view, I think that even if you could do this, you shouldn't. Every test case should be as simple as possible so everyone can execute it. If you really need this, perhaps you should split the test case to two different tests, and the second one will have the first as `prerequisite`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look in to it. Could it be that you meen Requirement instead of Prerequisite?

Comment: A prerequisite is a step or a set of steps that need to be executed before you start testing the actual test case. http://www.qualitytesting.info/forum/topics/what-is-prerequisite-where-we-use-prerequisite-in-the-test-case

Comment: Apparently this isn't possible in MTM.

Comment: Yeah, it is not part of MTM. The way we used is a step at the beginning of the test case describing the `prerequisite` without having expected results.